# Imperfetto indicativo al posto del congiuntivo

Tags: grammar, moods

Noto che spesso viene usato l'imperfetto al posto del congiuntivo, per esempio: se io facevo avrei, se io studiavo avrei... Quando è accettabile?

Comment: Penso che tu intenda l'imperfetto indicativo al posto dell'imperfetto congiuntivo, no? Tecnicamente, sono entrambi imperfetti.

Comment: @DaG: E anche al posto del congiuntivo trapassato. Per esempio: *Se studiavo, avrei passato l'esame* invece di *Se avessi studiato, avrei passato l'esame*.

Comment: Secondo il mio libro, a volte si usa l'imperfetto indicativo al posto del condizionale passato. Per esempio: *Se fossi venuto a casa mia mangiavamo una pizza insieme* o persino *Se venivi a casa mia mangiavamo una pizza insieme*.

Comment: Questi usi dell'imperfetto indicativo si tendono a fare nel registro colloquiale nel periodo ipotetico dell'irrealtà per parlare di fatti del passato.

Comment: Il libro a cui mi riferivo prima è *Nuovo Contatto C1. Corso di lingua e civiltà italiana per stranieri* di R. Bozzone Costa, M. Piantoni, E. Scaramelli e C. Ghezzi.

Answer (score 6):

Trovi un interessante riassunto su quello che dicono diversi studiosi su questo fenomeno nella pagina 54 della [tesi di dottorato di Entela Tabaku Sörman](http://su.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:739520/FULLTEXT01.pdf) (Stockholm University):

> Sabatini (1985: 167) sostiene che l’indicativo si estende sempre di più nel 
>   periodo ipotetico dell’irrealtà come in “se me lo dicevi, ci pensavo io”. Per 
>   Serianni (1986: 60), invece, la coppia congiuntivo/condizionale nel periodo 
>   ipotetico è abbastanza salda, nonostante la lunga tradizione anche letteraria 
>   del tipo con l’indicativo.
>
> In generale, gli studiosi sono d’accordo sul fatto che questo sia un tratto 
>   caratteristico della lingua parlata. Così Bertinetto (1986: 378) osserva che 
>   l’imperfetto ipotetico risulta essere di uso frequentissimo nella lingua 
>   parlata, specialmente in certe varietà substandard dell’italiano. Quando 
>   compare in per esempio testi letterari, allora è quasi esclusivamente nelle 
>   parti dialogate, con spiccata funzione mimetica dello stile colloquiale. Anche 
>   Berretta (1993: 213) sostiene che l’imperfetto ipotetico è una costruzione 
>   colloquiale e popolare, ormai piuttosto diffusa anche nell’uso medio.
>
> L’imperfetto ipotetico viene sconsigliato fermamente, per esempio, da 
>   Della Valle & Patota (2009: 119-120) nell’italiano scritto e in quello parlato 
>   in situazioni formali. Così, anche per Prandi (2011), che considera l’uso di 
>   questa forma come sconsigliabile, almeno nella lingua scritta, anche se vanta 
>   attestazioni già nell’italiano antico.
>
> Tra le ultime osservazioni sull’uso dell’imperfetto ipotetico si può 
>   segnalare quella di Bonomi (2010: 126), che osserva che l’uso semplificato del tipo “se sapevo non venivo” è molto diffuso nella lingua parlata 
>   informale, però si riscontra meno in quella scritta.
>
> L’indicativo nelle ipotetiche dell’irrealtà del passato, quindi l’imperfetto 
>   ipotetico, è per Serianni (2006a: 590) “un costrutto tipico del registro 
>   colloquiale, benché in espansione”. Il modulo più tradizionale per l’irrealtà 
>   nel passato, con il congiuntivo trapassato nella protasi e il condizionale 
>   presente o passato nell’apodosi è largamente diffuso anche nel registro 
>   colloquiale, sostiene Serianni.
>
> In Renzi *et al.* (2001), altresì, l’uso dell’imperfetto ipotetico è visto come 
>   appartenente alla variante colloquiale del sistema standard, presente talora 
>   però anche in livelli più alti. Questa variante colloquiale prevede la 
>   possibilità che l’indicativo imperfetto sostituisca il congiuntivo 
>   piuccheperfetto nella protasi e /o il condizionale composto nell’apodosi, 
>   come in per esempio *se lo sapevo prima, sarei arrivato in tempo a salutarti; 
>   se lo sapevo prima, arrivavo in tempo a salutarti; se l’avessi saputo prima, 
>   arrivavo in tempo a salutarti*.
>
> Patota (2003: 383) nella sua grammatica per stranieri è più restrittivo e 
>   normativo:
>
> > *Bisogna sottolineare che l’uso dell’indicativo imperfetto nella frase 
> >     condizione e/o nella frase-conseguenza dell’ipotesi irreale è normale 
> >     nell’italiano parlato ma è da evitare nell’italiano scritto, in cui è preferibile 
> >     usare il congiuntivo nella frase-condizione e il condizionale nella frase-conseguenza* (Patota 2003: 383).
>
> Questa citazione viene modificata nella pubblicazione successiva di Patota 
>   (2010: 302), dove l’osservazione “è da evitare” è scomparsa e il costrutto si 
>   presenta come un costrutto “normale nell’italiano parlato ma non così 
>   nell’italiano scritto in cui è preferibile usare il congiuntivo nella frase-condizione e il condizionale nella frase-conseguenza”.
>
> Per Prandi & De Sanctis (2011: 354, 449) l’imperfetto ipotetico 
>   appartiene alla forma dell’irrealtà nel sistema substandard del periodo 
>   ipotetico, comune negli usi colloquiali e in testi di registro più alto con 
>   funzione di mimesi del parlato spontaneo. È un uso tipico del registro 
>   informale.