# Qual è la forma corretta: "dovevo" o "avrei dovuto"?

Tags: verbs, tenses, conditional-mood

Buongiorno, volevo chiedere quale delle due forme sia più corretta:

> Forse non dovevo mangiare così tanto ieri sera

oppure

> Forse non avrei dovuto mangiare così tanto ieri sera.

Grazie.

Comment: Benvenuta su ItalianSE!!

Comment: Si sta parlando di un "desiderio irrealizzabile", quindi, in teoria si dovrebbe usare il [condizionale](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/condizionale_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) "avrei dovuto". Ma, come si spiega in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8346/imperfetto-indicativo-al-posto-del-congiuntivo), succede che, soprattutto nella lingua parlata, l'uso dell'imperfetto indicativo (cioè, in questo caso, "dovevo") al posto del condizionale si sta estendendo sempre di più.

Comment: Sullo stesso articolo della Treccani che ho messo nel link del commento precedente si legge "avrei voluto («volevo») farlo" come esempio di desiderio irrealizzabile.

Comment: A essere pignoli, in questo caso non è neppure un desiderio irrealizzabile. Il fatto di _dover mangiare poco_ era vero e continua a esserlo anche se uno ha mangiato tre polli arrosto. Quindi qui l'imperfetto indicativo mi sembra persino più accettabile che nel classico “se lo sapevo non venivo” (che pure è pienamente parte dell'italiano parlato e non solo).

Comment: @DaG: Quindi era corretto "dovevo" in questo caso?

Comment: @DaG: Può darsi che tu abbia ragione, ma "avrei dovuto («dovevo») farlo" è un esempio di "desiderio irrealizzabile" che dà la Treccani. E non sappiamo se il fatto di "dover mangiare poco" o di "dover farlo" nell'esempio della Treccani sia vero o no. La frase della domanda la potrebbe dire una persona che è ossessionata in modo maniacale con mantenere la linea, una persona che soffre di anoressia...

Comment: @Charo: D'accordo, grazie.

Comment: @SaraMonti: Ci sono molte sfumature fra il “corretto” e lo “scorretto”, in un ambito complesso come le lingue umane. Entrambe quelle frasi sono accettabili, la prima in un registro più colloquiale, la seconda in uno più formale. Da' un'occhiata anche ai link segnalati da Charo.

Comment: Grazie mille per le risposte, quindi la prima forma usata non è propriamente scorretta!

Comment: La frase intendeva che siccome ho esagerato nel mangiare e non sono stata bene di stomaco, era meglio se avessi diminuito le dosi"

Comment: @SaraMonti:  L'articolo della Treccani che ho messo nel link a me dà l'impressione che siano tutte e due corrette, anche se, per quanto so, nell'Italiano moderno la scelta con il condizionale si considera come più formale.

Comment: Qualcuno può scrivere una risposta?